# asp.net core db add null exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldQGN.png)

The linked domain is not null , backlinks are not null , and the remaining null fields are filled by ef while saving it to the db .
I still can't find why it's giving an error

this must be work but throw  exception , i dont find it why

Comment: What's your model about item? Besides, what's your Id?

Comment: Show call stack instead of images. Click **Copy Details** and update question.

Comment: problem solved, thanks. there is a problem coming from repository impl.